# How can I list the current user's posts?

Tags: 7, views

How can I list all posts of the current user? I know I should use Views, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'filter by current user' in the Views module.

Answer (score 1):

The core [Tracker](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/tracker) module does this per user.